# Php Mysql Join two tables with multiple codition and null records

Tags: mysql

I have tried to fetch records from 2 tables but it is not showing required output where my first table is ttreply

[image: ttreply table]

And another table is ttreplycount where count stored as below:

[image: ttreplycount]

I have tried to fetch value but it doesn't fetch records as i want my mysql query as below:

```
SELECT r.id, r.userid, r.`reply`, coalesce(x.votes,0) as Votes 
FROM `ttreply` r left join 
(SELECT sum(votes) as Votes from `ttreplyvotes` )x ON r.`post_id`=2
```

Which showing me output like this:

[image: Output]

What i needed is like this:

```
id  userid    reply                Votes
2   3       Testing 2nd reply      -2
3   3       Testing 3nd reply       0
4   3        rewsf                  0
```

Any help would be helpful.

Comment: How do you determine which row gets the votes value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the rows you want by moving the condition to the `where` clause:

```
SELECT r.id, r.userid, r.`reply`, coalesce(x.votes,0) as Votes 
FROM `ttreply` r cross join 
     (SELECT sum(votes) as Votes from `ttreplyvotes` ) x 
WHERE r.`post_id` = 2 ;
```

This will have `-2` for all three rows.  Why do you want the total on only one row?  How do you determine which row gets the total?

EDIT:

Oh, I think I understand:

```
SELECT r.id, r.userid, r.`reply`, coalesce(x.votes, 0) as Votes 
FROM `ttreply` r left join 
     (SELECT replyid, sum(votes) as Votes
      FROM `ttreplyvotes`
      GROUP BY replyid
     ) x 
     ON x.replyid = r.id
WHERE r.`post_id` = 2 ;
```